# How to read content from a docx file after upload that file using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, docx

I have a code to read data from a docx file, it's works fine in localhost, but after hosting it's not read data.

```
public static string GetTextFromWord(string paths)
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object path = paths;

        object readOnly = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {
            text.Append(" \r\n " + docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString());
        }

        return text.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: You assume there is a Microsoft Office installed *on your hosting server*. That will most likely not be the case (and for a good reason).

Comment: Is it possible? I am hosted my site on godaddy.

Comment: You would need to ask your provider, but I don't see why they would install a user software package like Office on one of their servers. You may want to pick another method to read word documents. Preferably one that does not require the Office Software installed.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/docx) for example looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` is part of the primary interop assembly (PIA) for Microsoft Office, which requires that Microsoft Office (specifically Word in your case) is installed on the machine. The PIA is primarily aimed at **desktop automation** (e.g. plugins for Word or other tools that enhance the Office experience).

In your case it looks like you want to parse a Word document on the **server**. For this you don't need an actual Word installation, which is good since, since it saves you a license and any other headaches involved getting Office installed on a (shared) server environment.

There are open-source libraries like [DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX) that you can use to extract data from Word documents. Another option is [Microsoft's own Open XML SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/).